# addJavascriptInterface in Web View Android

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

I have javascript like this:

```
GameManager.prototype.restart = function () {
     AndroidFunction.showMessage("Hai");
};
```

And to get string "Hai" in android, i can use this code and works

```
webView = (XWalkView) findViewById(R.id.walk_view);
webView .addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(), "AndroidFunction");
webView .loadUrl(someURL);

public class WebAppInterface {
@JavascriptInterface public void showMessage(String toast) {
  Toast.makeText(PlayGameViewActivity.this, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

But when i change the javascript to this:

```
GameManager.prototype.restart = function () {
     AndroidFunction.test.showMessage("Hai");
};
```

There is **test** between **AndroidFunction** and **showMessage**, and this is my java code:

```
webView = (XWalkView) findViewById(R.id.walk_view);
webView .addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(), "AndroidFunction.test");
webView .loadUrl(someURL);

public class WebAppInterface {
@JavascriptInterface public void showMessage(String toast) {
  Toast.makeText(PlayGameViewActivity.this, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

My WebAppInterface doesn't get any message from javascript instead get error message

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined

, My question is how to get **AndroidFunction.test.showMessage("Hai");**

Comment: Why cant you you use, `AndroidFunction_Test` or `AndroidFunctionTest`. The problem is that when you call `variable.another_variable`, the first variable is considered as an object.

Comment: @K Neeraj Lal : It's because my friend using swift language and he must use `another_variable` to get or post message to javascript.. and we work with one javascript project..